# Send data to a site to obtain a Json with php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm having an issue, the thing is that I was reading a json file with jquery, and it was working well, but now I have to make it read it in php, but the thing is that I was using some data to obtain the parts of the json with:

```
dataString = "id=" + id + "&todos=" + false;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://www.url.com/example",
data: dataString,
dataType: "json",

success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

And with this I had no problem, since I was sending the data to the site so it can give me the info that I wanted, but I have no clue of how to do it in php, i was trying with

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://www.url.com/example.json');
$json = json_decode($str, true); 
var_dump($str);
```

But of course the site its returning me nothing since I'm not sending the data

I hope there's a way. Thanks!

Comment: since you are posting the data along with the ajax request, you would need to use [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) to build a context that changes the method to post and sends the data. That is if you want to use file_get_contents. Or you could use curl, but you would end with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `curl` or `fsockopen` if the first is not present and cannot be enabled (pretty rare case).

Here how you do that with `curl`

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'id' => $id,
    'todos' => false
));
$json = json_decode( curl_exec($ch) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Kuhn is right.

Here's an example with stream_context_create:

```
<?php

$str = file_get_contents('http://www.url.com/example', false, stream_context_create(
                        array('http' => 
                            array('method' => 'POST',
                                'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                'content' => 'id=idVal&todos=false'))));
?>
```

Comment: I discourage this approach because is considered a good security practice to disable `allow_url_fopen` on servers. However, this taught me the existance of `stream_context_create`, hence thank you :P